# CUDA with OpenGL: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop

I am following the CUDA-by-example tutorial to set up OpenGL for graphics interoperation with CUDA. [**Here is what I'm following**](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/homepages/wrf/wiki/ParallelComputingSpring2014/cuda-by-example/chapter08/basic_interop.cu). When I get to the point of registering the buffer with CUDA runtime as a graphics resource and run the code, I get an error stating that all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable.

I can run other CUDA code no problem. I can use OpenGL to render graphics if I don't attempt to do the interoperation (so I can: swap memory to CPU, render in OpenGL, etc).

I don't think the CUDA device is doing anything at this point. I have tried closing all other windows to see if something else was using the resource, but that didn't change anything. Here is a short code snippet that I have showing my initialization process so far:

```
#include "common/gl_helper.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_gl_interop.h"    
#include "common/book.h"

#define DIM 1024

PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC    glBindBuffer     = NULL;
PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC glDeleteBuffers  = NULL;
PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC    glGenBuffers     = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC    glBufferData     = NULL;

GLuint bufferObj;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;

int main( void ) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    int dev;    

    int c=1;
    char* dummy = "";
    glutInit( &c, &dummy );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( DIM, DIM );
    glutCreateWindow( "bitmap" );

    glBindBuffer    = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBindBuffer");
    glDeleteBuffers = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glDeleteBuffers");
    glGenBuffers    = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glGenBuffers");
    glBufferData    = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBufferData");

    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObj);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, DIM*DIM*4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);

    memset(&prop, 0, sizeof(cudaDeviceProp));
    prop.major = 1;
    prop.minor = 0;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaChooseDevice(&dev, &prop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaGLSetGLDevice(dev));

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&resource, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard));
}
```

That last line is what returns the error. The `common/` files are from the CUDA-by-example book files, and I could post them if you'd like. I also tried just running the example in the book files (working code supposedly), but I still get the same problem. What do I need to do to resolve this?

System info: Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010 with CUDA 6.5. I have a GTX650 video card.

**I have tried test samples provided by Nvidia and none of the interop ones work. Even for the code I did not write. This code works on my laptop that has a GTX750M in it.**

Comment: How is `cudaGLSetGLDevice()` supposed to get the current GL context if you don't create and make one current until `glutCreateWindow()`?

Comment: @genpfault, I switched the code so that `glutCreateWindow` and other GLUT  stuff goes first (I changed my post). But the problem hasn't changed.

Comment: I added a link to the source code that I am referencing. As you can see `cudaGLSetGLDevice` occurs first there. Since it is written by Nvidia engineers, I saw no reason to doubt their expertise.

Comment: are you running this on Linux?  What is the configuration of your machine? Is it a notebook computer? Do you have more than one GPU? (If so, please list NVIDIA GPUs and any other GPUs in the machine, as well as the display configuration - what GPU is connected to the display(s))

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I updated the post. I am on Windows 7 x64, using Visual Studio. The GPU is GTX650. I only have that one.

Comment: OK. so from your edit, openGL interop isn't working on your machine at all. So fix it (hint, you probably have a GPU built into your CPU as well). This isn't a programming question any more - you might want to find a more suitable venue to find a solution, because it isn't really on topic here.

Comment: @talonmies, if you know how, could you tell me? I know `cudaGLSetGLDevice` is setting the GTX650 (because I looked at the properties of device 0), not integrated. Maybe a monitor is connected to the motherboard and it should be attached to the GPU? I'll try when I get to work...

Comment: I don't know - it is your hardware, on which you have installed software, which apparently doesn't work. It extremely difficult to diagnose what could be wrong without sitting in front of the machine, which only you are in a position to do. And as I already said, this is off-topic for [SO] - there is no programming question here. NVIDIA have support channels for this sort of thing. Try them.

Comment: If you do happen to have on-board graphics (ie. a non-NVIDIA GPU), and the OpenGL stack does happen to be running on that GPU, then that is certainly a reason why you might be seeing this failure.  It's important for you to give crisp, accurate answers to questions, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark here.  I specifically asked you to list NVIDIA GPUs and any other GPUs in the machine.  And you said GTX650 - only that one.  Now you're not sure if there may be integrated graphics?  The fact that you can run OpenGL code doesn't indicate anything useful in this context.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I'm sorry, I just thought you were referring to having multiple dedicated GPUs! It's not like I intentionally come to SO to troll... My integrated graphics can't even run CUDA, so I guess in my mind I don't even consider it being a GPU. I am in the process of deleting all old CUDA from my computer (I have like 4 version), after which I will try messing around with what integrated is doing.

Comment: @Mewa: If you want to add a solution to this question, then add it as an *answer*. Don't edit solutions into your question. It is perfectly OK for you to answer your own question and accept it as the solution. That way you don't leave an unanswered question lying around. I have rolled back you last edit for this reason

Comment: @talonmies :) It will just be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the interop does not work for examples provided with the CUDA installation (can be found in ProgramData/Nvidia Corporation/Examples), the problem is not the code, but rather the computer's configuration. I did, for good measure, first unistall all of my old CUDA versions and reinstalled CUDA 7.0. That didn't fix anything, so I moved on.

The problem in this case was caused by the following:

I had the monitors plugged into the motherboard to use integrated graphics for display, since in Linux, CUDA cannot be debugged if the same device is used for display and computation. I switched to Windows, and forgot to swap the monitors back to the GPU. When I ran my code, `cudaGLSetGLDevice` used the dedicated GPU, which was as expected. The OpenGL, however, was handled by the dedicated graphics card, since that is what was used for display. As such, when I attempted to register the interop using `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer`, the integrated graphics was used. Since my integrated card is not CUDA-capable, it threw the error about having no CUDA devices available.

The solution? Well:
Reboot the computer and go into the BIOS (do not swap monitors yet). In BIOS make sure graphics are set to use the dedicated GPU (PCIe setting, in my case). Plug the monitors into the GPU's video ports. Starting the computer up resulted in some pretty funky display until the Nvidia drivers started working (I had to reboot another time to get it to use both monitors). After that, running the example code in Nsight worked!

I hope that helps whoever else stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a OpenGL context before CUDA will recognize OpenGL capable devices. `glutCreateWindows` is what creates a OpenGL context when using GLUT.

Comment: I tried that (I think that's what you meant) and posted new code in my original post. But that didn't do anything? Maybe I did it wrong though.

Comment: I am not accepting this as the answer, because `cudaGLSetGLDevice` does **not** need to be after `glutCreateWindow`. This is outlined in all Nvidia code examples provided with CUDA toolkit installations. In fact, certain publications (by Nvidia engineers) state openly that `cudaGLSetGLDevice` must occur before any other runtime calls. So do most of the CUDA interop examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mewa: Yes the CUDA documentation state that no other **CUDA** functions must be called before `cudaSetDevice`; but **OpenGL is not CUDA**. And if you had carefully read the documentation of `cudaGLGetDevices` you'd seen this line:  `returns in *pCudaDevices at most cudaDeviceCount of the CUDA-compatible devices corresponding to the current OpenGL context. If any of the GPUs being used by the current OpenGL context are not CUDA capable then the call will return cudaErrorNoDevice. `

Comment: And the last sentence is probably the root cause of the problem in this case. FWIW, this answer is 100% correct, the comment by @Mewa is an incorrect interpretation of the documentation, and the downvote on this is completely undeserved.

Comment: The entire problem was caused by the monitor being plugged in to the motherboard instead of the GPU. The code I used is directly from the Nvidia examples for interop - there are many of these and they all use it the same way, `cudaGLSetGLDevice` occurs right at the beginning. FWIW, I never called `cudaGLGetDevices`, so I don't see its relevance to this problem at all. Furthermore, chain downvoting my previous questions is just petty. My code works in its original form, your solution did not fix my problem.

Comment: @Mewa: The issue people are taking is, that in a real world application you should always check the environment. Don't just blindly call `cudaSetGLDevice` and hope for the best. Instead gather information about the system and do sanity checks. For example in my CUDA programs there's always a device enumeration phase in which it is cross-checked that a) CUDA devices with the required capabilities are available at all and b) that these devices can be used for OpenGL interop where required.

Comment: @Mewa: You can combine that with a check *if(gl_context && cuda_devices && !cuda_gl_devices) => CUDA device not used for display*.